# Comparing Lead/Opportunity Data with a Custom Object

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, map

I am writing a trigger for a custom object Data_Vault__c where data such as Company Name and Postcode are entered, this data is then compared to corresponding fields on Lead and Opportunity, if a match is found a field on the Data_Vault__c record is changed to 'Match Found'.

Here is some trimmed down code of my trigger so far:

```
List<Lead> leadCompanyList = new List<Lead>([SELECT ID, Company 
                                             FROM Lead 
                                             WHERE isConverted = FALSE]);

List<Opportunity> oppCompanyList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT ID, Name
                                                          FROM Opportunity
                                                          WHERE StageName IN ('To Call Back','Quote Given','On Stop','In Contract - Diarised') ]);

Set<String> leadCompanySet = new Set<String>();
Set<String> oppCompanySet = new Set<String>();

for(Lead lComp : leadCompanyList){
        IF(lComp.Company != null){    
            leadCompanySet.add( lComp.Company.toLowerCase() );
        }        
}

for(Opportunity oComp : oppCompanyList){  
        IF(oComp.Name != null){
            oppCompanySet.add( oComp.Name.toLowerCase() );
        }
}

for(Data_Vault__c d : Trigger.New){

        if(leadCompanySet.contains( d.Company_Name__c.toLowerCase() ) || oppCompanySet.contains( d.Company_Name__c.toLowerCase() )  ){

            d.Company_Match__c  =   'Company Match Found';

        }
}
```

This is working fine for me but I would like to also add the Lead/Opportunity Id to another field on the Data_Vault__c record when a match is found but I am not sure of the best way to go about it. I have created a map that contains the Id and Company values:

```
Map<Id, Lead> mapCompanies = new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT Company FROM Lead 
                                                WHERE isConverted = FALSE]);

system.debug('map: ' +mapCompanies);
```

This map contains the Id and Company values that I need but I am not sure how to best use the data in this map to both compare the Company value and enter the ID of the lead to the Data_Vault__c record if a match is found.

Hopefully my requirement makes sense, any guidance on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: (For Lead) Instead if using a set : leadCompanySet , use a map. Store company name as key and the Id as the value (concatenate the Ids delimited by a comma/semicolon).
Then instead of doing: leadCompanySet.contains, do a map.get() and if the value is not null, store the value 'Company Match Found' and the value of the map.

I hope I make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.  It's important to note though this doesn't handle a situation where there are multiple leads or opps that match the Company name of your custom object.  The code below will only find a single match.  If there are multiple that match, it will only set the Id field on your custom object to one of the matches

```
map<String,Id> lead_opp_map = new map<String,Id>();

for(Lead l : [Select Id, Company From Lead Where isConverted = FALSE and Company != null]){
    lead_opp_map.put(l.Company.toLowerCase(), l.Id);
}

for(Opportunity o : [Select Id, Name From Opportunity Where StageName IN ('To Call Back','Quote Given','On Stop','In Contract - Diarised')]){
    lead_opp_map.put(o.Name.toLowerCase(), o.Id);
}

for(Data_Vault__c d : Trigger.New){
    If(lead_opp_map.containsKey(d.Company_Name__c.toLowerCase())){
        d.Company_Match__c = 'Company Match Found';
        d.Matching_Lead_or_Opp_Id__c = lead_opp_map.get(d.Company_Name__c.toLowerCase());
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is looking great so far, I still have a lot to figure out but this is looking like a perfect starting point. Thanks for the reply, I knew I would have to utilize a map in some way just couldn't figure out how to do it exactly.

Comment: No worries.  Come back with more questions if you run into any issues building this out further.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to get all of the related Id's when matches are found rather than just a single match but having trouble figuring it out. Would it be an easy amendment to the code or would it change quite a lot?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a conditional using the `contains` method, you can have another 'for's iterating over the first lists you declared, and then you would have a condition (if the names match) to make what you want to do. This way, you will have not only the `Company_Match__c` field, but also the IDs of both objects.